# Linq where doesn't exits in current context

Tags: c#

I have list of User and Department Like below:

```
   public class Users
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string jobTitle { get; set; }
            public int officeLocation { get; set; }
            public string userPrincipalName { get; set; }
        }



 public class Departments
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string department { get; set; }

            public string displayName { get; set; }
        }
```

Here is my `Json`

```
   "Departments": [
            {
                "department": "Azure",
                "id": "1",
                "displayName": "Thad"
            },
            {
                "department": "Visual Studio",
                "id": "2",
                "displayName": "Scott Hansalman"
            },
            {




   "department": "C#",
            "id": "3",
            "displayName": "Paul"
        }
]



"Users": [
        {

            "jobTitle": "Senior Program manager ",
            "officeLocation": "Redmond",
            "userPrincipalName": "thad.teams.com",
            "id": "1"
        },
          {

            "jobTitle": ""Technical Lead,
            "officeLocation": "Redmond",
            "userPrincipalName": "scott.teams.com",
            "id": "2"
        },
          {

            "jobTitle": "Development Engineer II",
            "officeLocation": "Canada",
            "userPrincipalName": "paul.teams.com",
            "id": "3"
        }
    ]
```

I want to `join` two list using `linq` where I would pass `id` of `user`
and get department.

I tried like this

```
var query = from user in Users
                        join dept in Departments
                             on user.id equals dept.id

                        select new
                        {
                            user.id ,
                            user.jobTitle,
                            user.officeLocation,
                            dept.department
                        }.where(id = 1) ;
```

But where clause doesn't seems okay,  say's `where doesn't exits in current context`

Comment: You are not allowed to use `where` method in a such way with query syntax

Comment: How do I filter then? before select?

Comment: Yes, try to add `where user.id == 1` before `select` statement and use `==` for comparison instead of  assignment `=`

Comment: Yes, where comes before select, and doesn't start with a period.

Comment: Well, let me have a try. Thanks @PavelAnikhouski

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work, you're just missing some `(` `)`s, and there is a syntax error in the where...

```
(from user in Users
                    join dept in Departments
                    on user.id equals dept.id
                    select new
                    {
                        user.id ,
                        user.jobTitle,
                        user.officeLocation,
                        dept.department
                    }).Where(c => c.id == 1) ;
```

But usually, the `Where` is done upfront, as query expression.

Comment: Yes yes I was thinking like this but cannot figure out. Thanks

Comment: Should be fixed... although, it's not as neat as one would like it to be.